# random seed to generate random number

Tags: java, random-seed

Idea:
Computer A: at 03h00 pm generate to 2 primes are 5 and 7
Computer A: at 03h02 pm generate to 2 primes are 17 and 29

Computer B: at 03h00 pm generate to 2 primes are 5 and 7
Computer B: at 03h02 pm generate to 2 primes are 17 and 29

I built an RSA program, and now I want to develop my program by improving the confidentiality for RSA program. If I success, we will not have to exchange the public key for each other as normal. I know I have to build a new random function to put a seed number into that function and I know that if 2 computers have same seed number will generate same random number in same time ,but I don't know the relation between seed number, real time.

Comment: There is no relation between seed and time, except that if you don't specify a seed, the time is used as a seed.

Comment: You are aware that the private key will then be the same as well?

Answer (score 3):

You don't state a specific question, so I'm assuming you are really asking if this is a good idea.

The answer is No.  Your seeds are essentially non-random.  If a 3rd party know what your methodology is, all they need to do is try "clock times" in the time interval they suspect that your key pairs were generated.  This gives a dramatically increased probability of regenerating the actual keys ... than if you had used *real* random numbers.